# Using Wildcard in CSV lookup with if/else statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, if-statement, import

This bit of code is from a python script I have that will search for the employee id column of an employee in a CSV file, then output it if it exists in the column.

What I am trying to do is, if anyone changes the column order in the CSV file, to throw me an error that Column 3 is no longer the Employee ID Column by checking the header of the column, in the csv file, to see if it contains part of the phrase Employee ID by using a wildcard.

```
import csv

with open('Report1.csv', 'rb') as user_file:
    reader = csv.reader(user_file)

    for column in reader:
        print column[2]
        employeeIid = column[2]

        if column[2] == 'Employee ID':
            print employeeIid
        else:
            print "Employee ID Column in CSV changed-please repair"
```

When I run the above code I get this:

```
Employee ID
123456
Employee ID Column in CSV changed-please repair
```

It prints the employee ID, as well as the warning error. How can i improve/fix my code?

Please note: that the Employee ID is Column 3 in the CSV file(not 2- bit i assume python use 0 as a start).

Also, How can I Disregard the header, and only print the Employee ID number (ex 123456) instead of the Header AND the actual number?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over the columns?

Comment: Look into `in` and `break`.

Comment: @James I think i am. Any pointers to understand this? i am fairly new to python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code is confusing rows and columns.

Each iteration of `reader` will return a row of data.
The first iteration returns the `header/columns` from your csv file.

Also, open your file in text mode using `r` instead of `rb`.

Example.

```
import csv

with open('Report1.csv', 'r') as user_file:
    reader = csv.reader(user_file)

    for row_idx, row in enumerate(reader):
        # check if header row
        if row_idx == 0:
            # check column 2 of this row
            if row[2].strip() != "Employee ID":
                print("Employee ID Column in CSV changed-please repair")
                break
        else:
            # to only print "Employee ID"
            print(row[2])
            # to print all columns in the row
            # print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: This worked somewhat. I did have to remove the `', '` portion of `print(', '.join(row))` or else it added many commas in the print output due to other hear fields...Also it printed names and email fields. I just want the Employee ID column.
Please correct me, or comment in script above on a couple things so i can understand and reuse this logic. 1. Was the logic to remove everything except the "Employee ID" thus the `!=`? and 2. I dont quite understand `print(', '.join(row))`-is this a function?. 3. `.strip()`function too? 4. `row in enumerate` what does this do?

Comment: 1. The logic was to check if `Employee ID` was the second column in your csv file. If it isn't, the file isn't read further.
2. The `join` function is a nice way to stitch data in a row together. You can replace the comma with any separator you want. Seeing a bunch of empty commas would imply reading of any empty row.
3. `.strip()` function removes any leading or trailing white spaces before text comparison.
4. `enumerate` is a nice way of generating indices in a for loop. `enumerate(reader) returns a tuple of two values - the index and the actual value.

Comment: To simply print `Employee ID`, change the `else` logic to
`else: print(row[2])`

Comment: perfect-this works wonderful now!!!! One more thing,  what does the `==0` do to the header row, what part of the code leave it out from printing?

Comment: I don't follow.
You want to print the header?
`if row_idx == 0:` is simply a check to see if we are on the first row.

Comment: the first row in CSV file is the Header Row and contains ```First Name, Last Name, Employee ID``` etc. When i run your updated code it prints all the Employee IDs in the 3rd column(or 2nd if we count from 0,1,2..)...also as expected it is NOT printing the "Employee ID" header of that column. What part of the code leaves it out? Hypotheticaly i wanted to include it, what would i do? Mainly im trying to understand how that part works- not to print the first row that contains headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142762/discussion-between-xtos-and-slakker).